# How to get tweet ID ....? i am using twitter SDK through fabric

Tags: ios, swift, twitter-oauth

```
Twitter.sharedInstance().APIClient.loadTweetWithID(TweetID,
    completion:<#TWTRLoadTweetCompletion##(TWTRTweet?, NSError?) -> Void#>)
```

How to use get tweet ID to fetch the information about the tweets?

Answer (score -1):

Try this code.

```
TWTRLogInButton* logInButton =  [TWTRLogInButton
                                 buttonWithLogInCompletion:
                                 ^(TWTRSession* session, NSError* error) {
                                     if (session) {
                                         NSLog(@"signed in as %@", [session userID]);
                                           } else {
                                         NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                                     }
                                 }];
logInButton.center = self.view.center;
[self.view addSubview:logInButton];
```

Comment: This is the method to use the twitter button for login....... i have already implemented it.....now i want to load tweets ......

Comment: you want to load all tweets or some specific tweets on table view